# How to solve extracting data with scrapy because from contacts doesn't do anything?

Tags: python, scrapy

```
    import scrapy
    import pycountry
    from locations. Items import GeojsonPointItem
    from locations. Categories import Code
    from typing import List, Dict

    import uuid
```

creating the metadata

```
    #class
    class TridentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name: str = 'trident_dac'
        spider_type: str = 'chain'
        spider_categories: List[str] = [Code.MANUFACTURING]
        spider_countries: List[str] = [pycountry.countries.lookup('in').alpha_3]
        item_attributes: Dict[str, str] = {'brand': 'Trident Group'}
        allowed_domains: List[str] = ['tridentindia.com']

    #start script
    def start_requests(self):
        url: str = "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"

        yield scrapy.Request(
            url=url,
            callback=self.parse_contacts
        )

   `parse data from the website using xpath`

     def parse_contacts(self, response):

        email: List[str] = [
             response.xpath(
            "//*[@id='gatsby-focus- 
            wrapper']/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a[2]/text()").get()
        ]

        phone: List[str] = [
            response.xpath(
            "//*[@id='gatsby-focus- 
             wrapper']/main/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/a[1]/text()").get(),
        ]
    
        address: List[str] = [
            response.xpath(
            "//*[@id='gatsby-focus- 
            wrapper']/main/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/ul/li[1]/address/text()").get(),
        ]

            dataUrl: str = 'https://www.tridentindia.com/contact'

         yield scrapy.Request(
            dataUrl,
            callback=self. Parse,
            cb_kwargs=dict(email=email, phone=phone, address=address)
         )
```

Parsing data from above
def parse(self, response, email: List[str], phone: List[str], address: List[str]):
'''
@url [https://www.tridentindia.com/contact'](https://www.tridentindia.com/contact%27)
@returns items 1 6
@cb_kwargs {"email": ["corp@tridentindia.com"], "phone": ["0161-5038888 / 5039999"],
"address": ["E-212, Kitchlu Nagar Ludhiana - 141001, Punjab, India"]}
@scrapes ref addr_full website
'''
responseData = response.json()

```
    `response trom data`
    for row in responseData['data']:
        data = {
            "ref": uuid.uuid4().hex,
            'addr_full': address,
            'website': 'https://www.tridentindia.com',
            'email': email,
            'phone': phone,
        }

        yield GeojsonPointItem(**data)
```

I want to extract the address (location) with the phone number and email of the 6 offices
from html because I couldn't find a json with data. At the end of the extraction I want to save it as json to be able to load it on a map and check if the extracted addresses match their real location. I use scrapy because I want to learn it. I am new to web scraping using scrapy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are  6 offices and none of them contain email. It didn't make sense, why have you included email item where it's  clear to look that there are no email in 6 offices and the way that you are using to extract data isn't correct and perpect. So you can try yhe next example.

**Code:**

```
import scrapy
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "test"

    def start_requests(self):
        url = 'https://www.tridentindia.com/contact'
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)


    def parse(self, response):

        for card in response.xpath('//*[@class="cp-correspondence typ-need-asst"]/ul/li'):
            yield {

                'phone':''.join(card.xpath('.//*[@class="address"]/span[2]//text()').getall()).split(':')[-1].replace('\xad','').strip(),
                'address':card.xpath('.//*[@class="address"]/span[1]/text()').get(),
                'url':response.url
                }
```

**Output as json format:**

```
[
    {
        "phone": "+91 - 161 - 5039999",
        "address": "E-212, Kitchlu Nagar Ludhiana - 141001, Punjab, India",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    },
    {
        "phone": "1800 180 2999",
        "address": "Trident Group, Sanghera – 148101, India",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    },
    {
        "phone": "0124 - 2350399",
        "address": "25, A, 15 Shahtoot Marg, DLF Phase-1, Sector 26A, Gurugram, Haryana-122002",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    },
    {
        "phone": "0172 - 4602593 / 2742612",
        "address": "SCO 20 - 21, Sector 9D, Madhya Marg, Chandigarh - 160009",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    },
    {
        "phone": "0755 - 2660479",
        "address": "Trident Limited, H.NO. - 3, Nadir Colony, Shyamla Hills, Bhopal - 462013",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    },
    {
        "phone": "01679 - 244700 - 703 - 707",
        "address": "Trident Limited, Sanghera Complex, Raikot Road, Barnala - 148101, Punjab",
        "url": "https://www.tridentindia.com/contact"
    }
]
```

Comment: Because I wanted to extract the email that is under the 6 cards with information and at the same time the hours of activity from 9 am to 6 pm. At the same time, I want the result to be in geojson format so that I can display it on the map, creating the street address as a reference.